# Plesk 12: Linking Php-Files from outside the document root desnt work (pure html will)

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, plesk

Hi i am using Plesk12 on Ubuntu14.04 with Apache2 an php5 as Apache-Modul. I have tried a lot of settings for my vhost, but Apache don´t executes php files from outside the document root. At the moment i use this setting for my vhost:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/***.de/httpdocs/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>
```

I have this problem only with php files from ouside the document root, if I link a php-file inside the codument-root it works find, if i link in pure html it also works fine.

Watched the apache logs but could not find an info.

Anybody an idea?

Comment: With the php setting  open_basedir i could solve the problem

Comment: Could you please add in question why you need keep something at outside of webspace root(/var/www/vhosts/***.de/) ? Or why you can't move it inside of webspace?